# How to import an excel file and execute queries after?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have this procedure that should import an Excel file using a job and then I have some queries that create some report and after all it export the reports.

But when I execute the procedure the job works correctly and it imports the Excel file but the rest of the code doesn't recognize the table that just imported and SQL Server throws this error:

> Job 'IMP' started successfully.
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Final_Result, Line 7
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.'New LP''.

but when I refresh the SQL Server database, the table 'New LP' exists.

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you used the single quotes in the table name? Because that would not be smart.

Comment: @JohnHC Yes. does it make a difference?